CROS Error When Embedding PowerBI to Blazor App
I'm hosting my Blazor Project which contain an embedded element from PowerBi. PowerBi embeddded element supposedly require a sign in to microsoft account. When debugging through localhost, the sign-in box appears just fine.

but when I run it in hosted domain, the pop up immediately closed as soon as it appeared. I assumed there is something wrong with the CORS. and i've add configuration to handle CORS.
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://report.capcx.com",
                            "https://app.powerbi.com")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

i've also made sure that the configuration is in the right order. does anyone know what might be missing here?

I have some assumptions. Firstly, if it's due to CORS issue, then I'm afraid this is because your app is trying to contact Power BI and this makes a "cross-region" scenario, therefore the CORS configuration should be done in Power BI instead of your app, but since we can't prove it, I could only say we can add .AllowCredentials(); to improve the CORS policy and just take a try, it won't cost much time.

Then my another assumption is around SameSite Cookie. Power BI might use cookies with a SameSite policy, so that we might try to add Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None and Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;, just take a try for testing purpose. We are now can't address the issue as there's no detailed error message or call stack trace for the symptom.

By the way, is this link about embed power BI report into .net core MVC app helpful for you?
